# How to display and pad into ostream?

Tags: c++

I am trying to write time (m_min) into a stream in the HH:MM format, [adding the spaces with zero if the numbers are single digit

My time module only holds the time in minutes but will display and read the time in the format of HH:MM

How can I correctly pad this format to display into the stream?

For example: 03:02, 16:55, 234:06)

```
std::ostream& write(std::ostream& ostr) const;
```

Comment: Look at [`std::put_time()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/put_time).  Or, you can simply split the minutes into hours+minutes and then use [`std::setw()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/setw) and [`std::setfill()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/setfill) to pad as needed.

Comment: You can do this with [c++ I/O manipulators](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip), `std::right` and `std::setw`  specifically.